# how to count same object attribute values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a large array with the following structure:

```
let data = [
  {
    name: 'name1',
    values: {...},
  },
  {
    name: 'name1',
    values: {...},
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    values: {...},
  },
  {
    name: 'name1',
    values: {...},
  },
  {
    name: 'name3',
    values: {...},
  },
  ...
]
```

I need to find a way to count how often each name appears as a name value inside the data array.

So in this example the result should look like the following array:

```
let nameCounts = [
  {
     name: 'name1'
     count: 3
  },
  {
     name: 'name2'
     count: 1
  },
  {
     name: 'name3'
     count: 1
  }
]
```

I'm struggling to find good way for this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) your array to an object that has names as keys and "count objects" as values. Then you can get your final array with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
let data = [{
    name: 'name1',
    values: {},
  },
  {
    name: 'name1',
    values: {},
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    values: {},
  },
  {
    name: 'name1',
    values: {},
  },
  {
    name: 'name3',
    values: {},
  }
];

var res = Object.values(data.reduce((a, {name}) => {
  a[name] = a[name] || {name, count: 0};
  a[name].count++;
  return a;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(res);
```

Note that I use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to get the `name` value from each "current" object in the reduce callback. And the `||` pattern is standard practice in JS land to assign a default if it's not present.

Also note @ibrahimmahrir's comment about using `Object.create(null)` to create a prototypeless object for the accumulator.

Comment: Absolutely... Maybe a little comment about the use of "||" operator and the `{name}` deconstruction would be nice to help understand?

Comment: Minor note: pass `Object.create(null)` instead of `{}` to `reduce` as initial value to be safe. `Object.create(null)` creates a prototypeless object. Your code will break if some object in the array has a name like `name: "toString"` or `name: "valueOf"` ...

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thanks, I've added small notes at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create an object with the `name` part as the key and let the counts accumulate as the values of that object, and then use [Object.prototype.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to transform this back into an array.

```
const reducer = (acc, {name}) => {
    acc[name] = acc[name] || 0
    acc[name] += 1
    return acc
}

data.reduce(reducer, {})
    .entries()
    .forEach(([name, count]) => { name, count})
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to this would be with [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) since `Map` is kid of made for this really :)

```js
let data = [{ name: 'name1', values: {}, }, { name: 'name1', values: {}, }, { name: 'name2', values: {}, }, { name: 'name1', values: {}, }, { name: 'name3', values: {}, } ];

const countBy = (arr, prop) => arr.reduce((r,c,i,a) => {
  r.set(c[prop], (r.get(c[prop]) || 0) + 1)  
  return i == a.length-1 ? 
    Array.from(r).map(([k,v]) => ({ name: k, count: v })) : r
}, new Map())

console.log(countBy(data, 'name'))
```

I made it in a form of a function mimicking what `lodash` [_.countBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#countBy) (which if you are using you wont get more concise than that) does but with slightly different output:

```js
let data = [{ name: 'name1', values: {}, }, { name: 'name1', values: {}, }, { name: 'name2', values: {}, }, { name: 'name1', values: {}, }, { name: 'name3', values: {}, } ];

console.log(_.countBy(data, 'name'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution using `Array#reduce` and `Array#map`.

```js
const data = [{name:'name1'},{name:'name1'},{name:'name2'},{name:'name1'},{name:'name3'}];

const q = data.reduce((s, { name }) => (s[name] = (s[name] || 0) + 1, s), {});
const r = Object.keys(q).map((key) => ({ name: key, count: q[key] }));

console.log(r);
```