# How can find the sum and count of json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Hi iam trying to group my json data in to sub json data.
here is my json data

```
        [
              {
                  "STATUS":"ACTIVE",
                  "AMOUNT":200,
                  "pENDING":100,
                },
                {
                  "STATUS":"NOTACTIVE",
                  "AMOUNT":100,
                  "pENDING":30,
                },
                {
                  "STATUS":"NOTACTIVE",
                  "AMOUNT":150,
                  "pENDING":10,
                }
          ]
```

and my expected result like

```
                 [
                     {
                     "STATUS":"ACTIVE",
                     "COUNT":"1",
                      "TOTAL AMOUNT":200,
                       "TOTAL PENDING":100
                      },
                      {
                      "STATUS":"NOTACTIVE",
                      "COUNT":"2",
                      "TOTAL AMOUNT":250,
                      "TOTAL PENDING":40
                      }
                 ]
```

I want the separate count ,sum of amount,sum of pending for each status
Could you please help me to find the result

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: const result= {};

data.forEach(entry => {
 if(!result[entry.STATUS]){
  result[entry.STATUS] = 0;
  }
  result[entry.STATUS]+= entry.AMOUNT;
});

console.log(result)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to count same object attribute values in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53601973/how-to-count-same-object-attribute-values-in-array)

Comment: but how can i get sum of two object along with count

Comment: @user5466590 Post what you have tried already into the question. Doesn't matter if it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it like this**

**Idea to handle such things.**

so here i am looping through the array and checking for status in the output object. if the status is already in output object i will update the required values. if it's not there than i will create a new one in output object.

```js
let arr =[
           {
            "STATUS":"ACTIVE",
            "AMOUNT":200,
            "PENDING":100,
           },
           {
            "STATUS":"NOTACTIVE",
            "AMOUNT":100,
            "PENDING":30,
           },
           {
            "STATUS":"NOTACTIVE",
            "AMOUNT":150,
            "PENDING":10,
           }
          ];
let output = arr.reduce((op,cur)=>{
  if(op[cur['STATUS']]){
    op[cur['STATUS']]['TOTAL_AMOUNT']+=cur['AMOUNT'];
    op[cur['STATUS']]['TOTAL_PENDING']+=cur['PENDING'];
    op[cur['STATUS']]['COUNT']++;
  } else {
       op[cur['STATUS']] ={
        'COUNT' : 1,
        'TOTAL_AMOUNT' : cur['AMOUNT'],
        'TOTAL_PENDING' : cur['PENDING'],
       }
  }
return op;
},{})
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend!

```js
var json = [{
    "STATUS":"ACTIVE",
    "AMOUNT":200,
    "pENDING":100,
},
{
    "STATUS":"NOTACTIVE",
    "AMOUNT":100,
    "pENDING":30,
},
{
    "STATUS":"NOTACTIVE",
    "AMOUNT":150,
    "pENDING":10,
}];
                
                
var result =  [];


var totalActive = 0;
var amountActive = 0;
var pendingActive = 0;

var totalNotActive = 0;
var pendingNotActive= 0;
var amountNotActive = 0;



for(var i=0; i < json.length; i++){
    var item = json[i];
    
    if (item.STATUS.toString() == "ACTIVE"){
        totalActive +=1;
        amountActive = amountActive + item.AMOUNT;
        pendingActive = pendingActive + item.pENDING;
    }
    else
    {
        totalNotActive +=1;
        amountNotActive = amountNotActive + item.AMOUNT;
        pendingNotActive = pendingNotActive + item.pENDING;
    }
                
}

result.push({ "STATUS" : "ACTIVE" ,    "COUNT" : totalActive.toString(),     "AMOUNT" : amountActive.toString(),    "pENDING" : pendingActive.toString() })
result.push({ "STATUS" : "NOTACTIVE" , "COUNT" : totalNotActive.toString(),  "AMOUNT" : amountNotActive.toString(), "pENDING" : pendingNotActive.toString() })


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to fix your own method I would suggest something like this. I tried to do it generic in case you would find it more useful, although this solution would have a problem if the AMOUNT or PENDING entries are not numeric.

```
const IDENTIFIER = 'STATUS' 
const result= {}; 

data.forEach( entry => { 

    //  Check is this status exists, if not, create one
    if(!result[entry[IDENTIFIER]]){ 
        result[entry[IDENTIFIER]] = {}
    } 

    //  For each item in the entry add the value
    Object.keys(entry).forEach( item => {
        //  Only sum the items that are not the identifier
        if(item !== IDENTIFIER){
            result[entry[IDENTIFIER]][item] = (result[entry[IDENTIFIER]][item] || 0) + entry[item];
        }
    })

});
```

Hope you find this useful